# Hiding a div when another is shown

Tags: javascript, html, hide

So, I have a nav element with an unorder list that I use as tabs.  There are three, you click one and it shows a div in the website.  However, I want it so that if you click another, it will hide the one currently being shown, and then show the one you clicked.  But I can't seem to get it right.  Here is the function I have:

```
function display(action, id)
 {
 if (action == 'show')
 {
 document.getElementById("page"+id).style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("link"+id).href= "javascript:display('hide', "+id+")";
 }

if (action == 'hide')
 {
 document.getElementById("page"+id).style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("link"+id).href= "javascript:display('show', "+id+")";
 }
 }

</script>
```

I tried to do something like

document.getElementById("page"+id+1).style.display = "none";

I thought that it would change the display style to none of the div with an id one more than the current, but instead it does nothing.  What would I add to this to have it hide all currently open tabs?

Comment: Could you paste the html aswell?

Comment: Just for future reference: if you end up using jQuery, you could try using `toggle()` (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

also you can store the `DIV` name in a `Hidden Input`

http://jsfiddle.net/we2AJ/

```
<body>
    <script language="javascript">
        function MyFunction(divName){

        //hidden val
        var hiddenVal = document.getElementById("tempDivName"); 

        //hide old
        if(hiddenVal.Value != undefined){
            var oldDiv = document.getElementById(hiddenVal.Value); 
            oldDiv.style.display = 'none'; 
        }

        //show div
            var tempDiv = document.getElementById(divName); 
            tempDiv.style.display = 'block';              

        //save div ID
            hiddenVal.Value = document.getElementById(divName).getAttribute("id");

        }
    </script>
    <input id="tempDivName" type="hidden" />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" OnClick="MyFunction('myDiv1');">Show myDiv1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" OnClick="MyFunction('myDiv2');">Show myDiv2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" OnClick="MyFunction('myDiv3');">Show myDiv3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <div id="myDiv1" style="background-color:red; height:200px; width:200px; display:none">
        myDiv1
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv2" style="background-color:yellow; height:200px; width:200px; display:none">
        myDiv2
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv3" style="background-color:green; height:200px; width:200px; display:none">
        myDiv3
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd rather use a global javascript variable var visible='myDiv1' -outside of the function then remove the hidden input type. Use that global variable to store which content is visible at the time that a link/tab is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the structure of this code by leveraging css classes. First, use `getElementsByClassName` to gather all your nav items. Then attach a click handler to them that points to your toggle code.

In the togglecode, add a class for the shown element and remove it for the old one. I made assumptions about your html structure, but this should be easily adaptable. classList isn't supported by < IE7, but you can [substitute in a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript) to handle this if support is necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Q4vy/1/

```
<div class="nav show"><span>A</span></div>
<div class="nav"><span>B</span></div>
<div class="nav"><span>C</span></div>
<script>
    //get nav items
    var navElems = document.getElementsByClassName('nav');

    //attach click handler to each
    for (var i = 0; i < navElems.length; i++) {
        navElems[i].onclick = toggleVisible;
    }

    //handle click events
    function toggleVisible() {
        //hide currently shown item
        document.getElementsByClassName('show')[0].classList.remove('show');
        //show clicked item
        this.classList.add('show');
    }
</script>
```